# Android - unregistered receiver logcat error

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have made the nect code on the MainActivity class -

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Setting a receiver - to know if the user is charging his mobile
        receiverAcDc = new ChargingReciver();
        IntentFilter filterAcDc = new IntentFilter();
        filterAcDc.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED);
        filterAcDc.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED);
        registerReceiver(receiverAcDc, filterAcDc);

}
```

Now i've also added the next code in the MainActivity -

```
   @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();


    // Trying to closing the receivers when the user leaving the activity
    try {

        unregisterReceiver(sea);
        unregisterReceiver(receiverAcDc);

    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
```

Now the thing is - that when i leaves the app (by pressing back for example) - i get the next logcat error -

```
01-15 15:05:46.421: E/ActivityThread(2639): Activity com.example.myplaces1.view.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.example.myplaces1.reciver.ChargingReciver@415d6d98 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

So what should i do in order to not get this logcat error?
Thanks for any kind of help

The receiver that gives me the error is on separate class and this is it's code -

```
public class ChargingReciver extends BroadcastReceiver{


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         String reciveAction = intent.getAction();

         // If the device is connected to a power supply 
        if (Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED.equals(reciveAction)) {
            // Notify the user the device is being charged 
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.charging, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // Notify the user the device is disconnected from power supply 
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.charging_no, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you register your receiver in this way, it lives for as
long as the component lives and Android sends events to
this receiver until the creating component itself gets
destroyed.

It’s your task to handle the lifecycle correctly. Thus when
you add a receiver dynamically, take care to unregister the same receiver in the onPause() method of your Activity!I suggest to register the receiver in the onResume() method of your Activity and to unregister it in your onPause() method.

Comment: well i tired the manifest thing - Still got the logcat error. I have also tired registering the receiver in the onResume() and unregister it at the onPause() - BUT still same logcat error